# Correctly load data in listview from startactivityforresult

Tags: android

**GOAL**

What I am trying to do:

Click on my search button and my database is queried with the results passed in. If nothing is found, we are taken to an activity which says so, but if results are found they are loaded into a list.

**What I have done**

When I click on the search button I call `startActivityForResult` then this intent calls an activity (whose layout consist of a list_view). The search button also pass along my parameters and query my database.
if there are no results then an activity saying "No Records" is displayed" 
and if there are records the else condition is true and the records are loaded in the list

**PROBLEM**

The problem I am experiencing is, when the list is loaded, if I want to go back to my search form, I must press the back button a total of three times. I am not entirely sure but I believe this strange behavior is stemming from me not returning a result to the started activity when the else clause is invoked.

I have placed what I think is the important part of my code below, would appreciate any assistance

Main Activity

```
  private void startStudentQuery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), retrieveStudentData.class);
        intent.putExtra("firstname", firstname);
        intent.putExtra("lastname", lastname);
        //startActivity(intent);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);// Activity is started with requestCode 2


    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          if (requestCode == 2) {
              Intent X = new Intent();
              X.setClass(getBaseContext(),NotFound.class);
              startActivity(X);
        }

    }
```

retrieveStudent Activity

```
//this activity is a listview  
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_student)
}


//Left out some code, just showing the main parts
    public class StudentAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {


//return result to show Activity if no records are found
       if (jsonArray.length() == 0) {

                        Intent intent=new Intent();
                        setResult(2,intent);
                        finish();


                    } else {//Show list if records are found
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jRealObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            Student student = new Student ();

                            student.setFirstname(jRealObject.getString("f_name"));
                            student.setLastname(jRealObject.getString("l_name"));
                            student.setImage(jRealObject.getString("image"));
                             studentList.add(student);

                        }
                    }
```

Comment: just Write Finish(); after startActivity(); Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

In `startStudentQuery`, you should call `startActivityForResult` only, but now you have called `retrieveStudentData` twice.

Comment: Oh yea i commented one, as I should, however when ever I search and I find results, if i click the "Back" button, it takes me to the Student not found page.

Comment: `onActivityResult`, you should check request code and result code are both equal to 2 in order to show no result found.

Comment: I noticed I have request code in the if statement not result code. that was my error